# memory usage of mmap on shm_open or memfd_create

Tags: linux, mmap

I need named growing shared memory for my application. Earlier I used memory mapped files, however they became too slow with many IOps. My boss decided to move those files into a ramdisk. I suspect mmap from always making its own memory buffer for both regular files and ramdisk. Is there any difference between ramdisk and shm_openo r memfd_create except lifetime ? Does mmap created pagetable just link to memfd's buffer or mmap creates a copy and memory is consumed twice ?

Regards, Martin

Comment: Do you actually need the memory mappings to have disk storage?  Would you be happy with an anonymous mapping that doesn't cause anything to be written to disk?

Comment: Persistence would be nice bonus, but I'm okay with just keeping memory handle open as long as possible in helper process. Like I wrote, mmap on regular file is too slow.

Comment: So you have two different processes that need to access the same mapping?  Is one of them the child of the other process, or do they need to be launched independently?

Comment: They are launched independently. Consumers are web pages and producer is outside webserver.